# SVN Commit on files changed, deleted, or added outside the svn control

Tags: svn, resources, conflict

I'm often changing files not from subversion, but from finder, or other sources.  Recently, for example, I updated some plugins from a wordpress setup that I've created a local svn repository for, but notably, the plugins, on update are in conflict with what's in the svn.  Add to that that I didn't delete or add certain files from svn, and when I do:

svn status

...many of the files are marked as ! and so forth.

If I do a cleanup, it doesn't seem to resolve the conflict (I'm not talking about resource conflicts, which can be fixed by doing an svn diff).

How do I resync files changed outside of the context of svn, and prep them for commit in the appropriate way.  If I'm not making sense, just say so, and I'll try and clean up/edit this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [svn_load_dirs.pl](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s04.html#svn-ch-7-sect-4.2).  It's designed for vendor branches, which isn't exactly what you're doing, but it should handle what you're trying to do without too much trouble.

Comment: Not exactly the answer I was looking for, but I'm marking it as the answer since you've waited so patiently, ha.